# Customize ListView control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

I would like to achieve the following design in ListView control, but I don't know how to get it. It's a shame but I don't understand how `subitems` works so I can't do that by myself.

[image]

Comment: it wont do it that like that - you cant assign multiple subItems to each LVI (which is what that amounts to).  What you might want is to use Groups where each Person is a Group.

Comment: Why not just use a gridview?

Comment: have you looked at TreeView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms???

Comment: The question is really what you want to achieve beyond the layout. You can get a similar layout with: ListView, DataGridView,  TableLayoutPanel and the TreeView. For the 1st three you will have to leave the 1st column empty for the repeating values. How exactly shall the speparating lines look like? TreeView won't really give you columns nor grid lines, I guess I'd rule it out.. DGV don't span anything and are a paint to style wrt their grid lines.

Comment: Learning about subitems and groups in ListView is an effort very well spent!

Comment: Hmm now I am thinking that groups would be more appropriate. As @Plutonix said - every Person would be a Group. But I don't know how to code it. Yeah I should learn about these

Comment: `thisNewLVI.Group = lv.Groups(n)` where n==the index of the group to add to.  or `lv.Groups(n).Add(thisnewLVI)`